# How can I show that the function in my problem is lebesgue integrable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

The function $f_n$: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f_n(x):=\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)\frac{1}{n}\exp(-\frac{x}{n})$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now: How can I show that $f(x):=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{f_n(x)}$ is lebesgue integrable?

I know that f(x) has to be nonnegative and Riemann integrable (How can I show that?). Are there any more criteria?

My problem is mostly that I dont know how to handle the $\chi(x)$.

**EDIT:** (Im new here, so please tell me in case I sould open a new question for this)

G. Sassatelli helped me in the comments to solve the first part of my problem.

Now I have to show $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) d\lambda(x) \neq \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x) d\lambda(x)}$.

Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: Well, it's nowhere a general criterion, but in this case one can say that $f=0$.

Comment: I thought about that, but it seemed to simple.  
So $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$  
$\rightarrow f$ is non-negative and Riemann integrable  
$\Rightarrow f$ is lebesgue integrable (?)

Comment: Well, I'm not that familiar with subtleties of Riemann integration, so what I'd say would be: 1) $f\equiv0$ is continuous, hence measurable 2) $\int_\mathbb{R} |f|\,dx =0<+\infty$, therefore $f$ is Lebesegue-integrable.

Comment: What do you need to show here? The limit is $0$ and  so  Lebesgue integrable since it is Riemann integrable. If you are supposed to show that the limit operation can be interchanged with the integral then  you can check directly that in the Riemann case, this is not true because each improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty }f_{n}dx$ gives you $1$ whereas the limit function is $0$

Comment: Yes, I have to show exactly that. I edited my question to make it clear.
So it is enough to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty }f(x)dx \neq \lim\int_{0}^{\infty }f_{n}dx$?

Comment: Good. So integrate each $f_{n}$ and you wll get $1$ for each $n$. But the limit function is $0$ so now you have your inequality.